# Wrong command timeout in EF Core SQL Server connection

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, timeout

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API with EF Core for database access. In production, some SQL commands are failing with a timeout.

> Failed executing DbCommand (30,188ms) [Parameters=[@__country_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']

In the error message, the `CommandTimeout` is 30 seconds. Thus it fails after 30 seconds.

But both, the connection string and the `dbContext` in the code set the timeout to 600s.

Connection string:

```
Server=SQLServer;Initial Catalog=Database1;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user1;Password=1234;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=600;
```

Set the command timeout in the constructor of API controller:

```
myDbContext.Database.SetCommandTimeout(600);
```

Why is this ignored and where do the 30 seconds come from?

Comment: The connection string sets the **connection timeout** - ***NOT*** the command timeout - those are two different timeouts!

Comment: Ok, but the 2nd one in the code sets the command timeout and that seems also to be ignored.

Comment: 30 seconds is the default CommandTimeout. CommandTimeouts are typically set on Command objects directly, or you can set them on Connection objects before creating any Command objects from them (they'll inherit the Connection's CommandTimeout value). If you want to set one CommandTimeout for an entire DBContext you should do that from its options builder via [UseSqlServer's ProviderOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#configuring-dbcontextoptions).